# mySQL count for my property list

Tags: mysql, count

i have 50 property with different zip code in databese. I want to get the total count of each zip code.

I want to show the total count like this

```
92508 (10)

30238 (5)

90026 (8)

23601 (15)
```

Comment: post the table structure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, use `CONCAT` to build a string and `COUNT` with `GROUP BY` to count by a particular value:

```
SELECT CONCAT(ZIPCode, ' (', COUNT(*), ')')
FROM Properties
GROUP BY ZIPCode
```

Comment: OK, got it - I was wondering how you did the display :) I'll take a look.

Comment: <?php 
include"connection.php";

$checke = "SELECT DISTINCT porperty_zip FROM property_list "; 
$rsd = mysql_query($checke);
?>
<table width="600" style="font-size:12px; border:1px solid #000000; text-align:center;" cellpadding="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
<td><strong>Zip</strong></td>

  </tr>
  <?php
  //Print the contents
  
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsd))
  {
   

  ?>
        <tr>
 <td><h2><?php echo $row['porperty_zip']; ?></h2></td>
  </tr>
       <?php
  } //while
  ?>

Comment: I'm not a PHP expert, but I think you can just name the `CONCAT(...)` column in the query I gave you and it will work with the code you pasted. Try adding `AS porperty_zip` to the `SELECT` list in your `$checke` query: `$checke = SELECT CONCAT(ZIPCode, ' (', COUNT(*), ')') AS porperty_zip FROM Properties GROUP BY ZIPCode`. Also note that the `mysql` PHP library is deprecated and has been replaced by `mysqli` or `PDO`.